# cairngorm 3 architecture

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm, flex3

I heared the cairngorm is not a framework and parsely framework is inbuilt(IOC container). So we here no need to use the frontcontroler to control the request to respose. Can any one please send ma clear architecture of the cairngorm3.

I had searched documents for cairngorm 3 architecture but not found anywhere.

Is it necessary to know the cairngorm2 or parsely framework (IoC container) or design patterns for learning cairngorm3 architecture.?

Thanks,
ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need is written here :

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/CairngormGuidelines

As already said , Cairngorm3 is not a framework, it's more like an architecture blueprint, guidelines and some libraries. So you can use CG3 with a "standard" MVC framework. I would stay away from Cairngorm2 if I were you.
Adobe uses mainly Parsley, but you can use CG3 with Swiz, Spring Source, Robotlegs, ...